# I have a table like below I want the latest entry to be displayed

Tags: mysql, sql

The query which I am using now is below:

```
select ur.uid
     , ua.user_activity_min_budget
     , ua.user_activity_max_budget
     , ua.user_activity_bedroom
     , ptm.property_type_description
     , cm.city_name
     , lm.locality_name
     , ua.user_activity_datetime
  from user_registration ur
  join ksl_user_activity ua 
    on ua.registered_user_uid = ur.uid 
   and ua.user_activity_uid = ( select max(ua0.user_activity_uid) from ksl_user_activity ua0)
  join ksl_locality_master lm 
    on lm.locality_uid = ua.user_activity_area
  join ksl_city_master cm 
    on cm.city_uid = lm.city_uid
  join ksl_property_type_master ptm 
    on ptm. property_type_uid = ua.user_activity_property_type
 where date(ua.user_activity_datet±me) >= '20l7-07-24' 
   and (lm.city_uid = 1 or lm.city_uid=2)
 order 
    by ur.uid
```

The raw output s as this image shows:

[image]

The data is what I get now but I want the latest entry for uid 3,15,33

The reason why I have done the below is and `ua.user_activity_uid=(select max(ua0.user_activity_uid) from user_activity ua0)`.

ksl_user_activity table has a primary key `user_activity_id` which has the maximum value for the latest entry but I am not getting any data when I include this in my query.

I also tried and `ua.user_activity_uid=(select ua0.user_activity_uid from user_activity ua0 order by ua0.user_activity_uid desc limit 1)`

This is also not working.

Answer (score 1):

use max() function and sub-query

```
    select t1.uid from user_activity t1
    inner join 
    (select uid,max(user_activity_datetime) as user_activity_datetime from   user_activity group by uid
    ) as t2 on  
    t1.user_activity_datetime=t2.user_activity_datetime
    and t1.uid=t2.uid
```

Comment: where should i give this line of Query

Comment: @Geek124 this query will return last active user list

Comment: @Geek124 does it helps

Comment: .Iam not getting it moreover uid and user_activity_id are primary keys o two different tables user_registration and ksl_user_activity

Comment: iam sorry but i didnt get my requires answer